# How to use TCP-based HTTP to download image?

Tags: c, http, tcp

I got some images to download using HTTP. I got these images' URL, how to build the TCP-based HTTP buffer to download the image?

I got no library in my current platform, the only supported language in this platform is C, so I have to build the HTTP buffer for these resources.

Currently I have build the normal API request, they are all HTTP request, every request have 0  or more parameters. But the image request got only a URL, such as **http://some-image.jpg**, it seems just a **download** job, no API parameters, no authorization, it's simple, but how to construct the TCP request?

Comment: What platform? Can you use libraries? Need some more information here.

Comment: My platform got its own TCP library, but no HTTP library, its TCP library is the same like POSIX, but I just don't know hot to build the TCP request buffer.

Comment: Is there any mention of 'Sockets' in the documentation for this TCP library?

Comment: To @user978122: Yes, there are some TCP APIs like `tcp_connect`, `tcp_read` and `tcp_write`, but no more, these APIs have nothing to do with the HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample, I build my TCP request like that:

```
sprintf(tcp_send_buf, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", img_path, img_host);

/* I wrapped TCP APIs for convenient, hope you understand it... */
set_host_and_port(img_host, 80);
tcp_send(tcp_send_buf, strlen(tcp_send_buf), recv_callback);
```

On my `recv_callback`, I got the server response like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 42299
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Jul 2007 07:58:47 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "e2c8b5d17ebcc71:15d5"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 May 2012 01:33:57 GMT

<binary image data>
```

I downloaded the image from Chrome, and it's size is the same as `Content-Length: 42299`, I think I got the image buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to implement HTTP protocol or a subset of it. There are open source implementations. For example:

https://github.com/bagder/curl/tree/master/lib

https://github.com/joshthecoder/libhttp

Comment: Another one to try: [http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser). This one just parses the HTTP stream and you supply your own socket handling. In your case that should be easy since it is just a client.

Comment: Also, have a look at [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/). It does over-simplify a little and not all of the information is 100% accurate, but I think you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> how to build the TCP-based HTTP buffer to download the image?

Stop thinking TCP. It has it's own buffers which have nothing to do with what's happenning at the HTTP level.

You really don't want to implement your own HTTP stack - it's not trivial. There are several well-written ones already available - I'd recommend using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: libcurl seems too big for my device, I just want to download the image, according to [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample) recommended by @Ian Goldby, if the download is a `jpg`, not a `html`, will the server also return the image in some encoding?

Comment: @coanor The server tells you the data type with the Content-Type header (e.g. image/jpeg), and then the data itself follows after the HTTP headers. Binary data is no problem.

Comment: But you still need to handle different transfer encodings.

Comment: to @symcbean: Yes, but the first mission is to download the image, isn't it? Fortunately, I got a idea.

Comment: No, downloading the file is **dependent** on implementing the protocol by which the file is transfered. This is TRANSFER encoding, not CONTENT encoding